# How to iterate over an array skipping every second element?

Tags: ruby

How to write this type of for loop in ruby?

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i+2) {
}
```

I know how to write it if step is 1, but if step > 1, how to make it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify `.step` size as an argument actually:

```
(0...arr.length).step(2) { |i| puts arr[i] }
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to use **[Array::each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)**:

```
 arr.each_slice(2) { |n| p n.first }
```

Comment: upvoted this one, I'd just clean the last part `arr.each_slice(2).map(&:first)`

Comment: @floum, I think xdazz means `arr.each_slice(2) { |n| < do something with n.first > }`. You could also write it `arr.each_slice(2) { |f,_| < do something with f > }`

Answer (score 2):

```
(0...arr.length).step(2) do |n|
end
```

OR

```
for i in (0...arr.length).step(2) do
    puts arr[i]
end
```

step is used for incrementing n value and this loop will continue till arr.length

Comment: You should show that this yields the indices and you have to do the array look-up in addition.

Comment: @undur_gongor I didn't get you

Comment: `arr.each { | n | p n }` prints the array elements. `(0...arr.length).step(2) { |n| p n }` prints not the (even) elements but the indices. You'd need `(0...arr.length).step(2) { |n| p arr[n] }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too:

```
> arr = Array('a'..'z')
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] 
> arr.select.each_with_index{|k,i| k if i.even?} 
#=> ["a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k", "m", "o", "q", "s", "u", "w", "y"]
```

I love `step` and `slice` method by which already answered so this is just another approach. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A million and one ways to solve Array problems. If you don't actually need the loop this will pull the values easily

```
a = (0..20).to_a
a.values_at(*(0..a.size).step(2))
#=> => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop it can be done as follows:-

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]  
i=0
begin
    puts arr.at(i*2)
i += 1
puts "value of i is #{i}" 
end while (i*2) < arr.length
```

Comment: where 2 is the step you would like to take.